# Extracting integer ID from URL in SQL

Tags: sql, regex

Given a url like `https://xyz.abc.yahoo.com/issues/80483987/tasks/1`

How can write a SQL query to replace/extract urls like this with their integer ID that is `80483987`

Using `REGEXP_REPLACE(mystr, r'[^\d]+', ' ')` gives me `80483987 1`

The `1` at the end being a problem.

Comment: Which SQL version?

Comment: What makes `80483987` any different than any other number(s) ? No use trying to help you if you can't answer the question that is the core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply `REGEXP_EXTRACT` the numbers after `/issues/` substring:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(mystr, r'/issues/([0-9]+)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iIZVzT/1).

The `/issues/` will get matched and `([0-9]+)` will *capture* 1 or more digits into capturing group #1 and that is the value returned by `REGEXP_EXTRACT`.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `REGEXP_REPLACE` twice:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(mystr, r'^[^\d]+', ''), r'/.*$', '')
```

***Explanation***

The inner call removes all leading non-digits, the outer call removes the suffix after the id. `^` and `$` are so-called anchors and do not represent a character but the abstract (0-length) notions of 'beginning / end of the test string'.
   This will work in all common regex flavors and engines.

The solution hinges on the numerical id constituting a location segment in the url.

Note that the approach is fragile: eg. it will fail for urls with a port number.